# Resulting precision of Math.ceil() and similar

Tags: java

I couldn't see in the java docs or references anywhere where it specifies what precision a resulting double, 12.875376 for example, would have after calling something like Math.ceil().

I tried it out and I get 1 decimal place, but is anyone aware of any explicit specification regarding this? Or at least should I be confident that this will always be the case across different platforms, etc.

I came across the question in a test (does Math.ceil(17.5638) result in 1>  18.0 or 2> 18.0000   ).

Cheers.

Comment: BTW `System.out.println(18.0 == 18.00000);` returns `true` so there is no different in your test question.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between 18, 18.0 and 18.0000? They are just different representations of the same double number, 18 (exactly).

Comment: They are different though. They have different scales & precisions, which is important.

Comment: @Aaron: Not in floating-point.

Comment: Is the precision & scale (as far as java is concerned at least) only an issue then if i'm using a BigDecimal or something? So I'd have to set those seperatey?

Comment: See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Math javadocs states ceil returns a value which is equal to a mathematical integer. It makes no sense to talk about its precision. It is exactly 18. As for 18.0 or 18.00 it's only a matter of its string representation. You can make it 18.000 for example. As for the question in the test in my opinion it is simply incorrect.

Comment: It makes perfect sense (and removes my perceived ambiguity) when you word it like that. Thanks.   I was just considering the fact that it returns a double, but missed the point that as a double representation of an integer it would necessarily show a .0

Comment: I would say that the answer to the question in the test is simply "yes".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth There were a lot of poorly crafted questions in the test. And this is what investment banks are using to pre-screen candidates :s

Answer (score 2):

The "precision" displayed is actually more due to the format presented when converting a double with an integer value to a String. Since `Math.ceil` returns a value equal to an integer, and IEEE 754 doubles can represent integers up to +/- 2^53 with perfect precision, the correct answer would be "perfect precision".

How integer-valued doubles are presented as Strings is a different question entirely, and I suspect it would be very language-dependent.

Comment: So it is guaranteed that `ceil(12.87537) == 13` (for any such values)?

Comment: Yes as long as the value is within +/- 2^53

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ceil(x)` is exact for all values of `x`. If `x` is so big, or so negative, that the next integer up may not be exactly representable, `x` is so large magnitude that all the representable numbers, including `x`, are integers, and it is its own ceiling.

Given the exactness, the only issue is how the conversion to string for output handles integer-valued doubles. That can be changed, if necessary, using a DecimalFormat.